# Redis update with query

Tags: redis, updates, atomic

I'm new to `redis`, but from reading the docs I couldn't find if it is possible to update a value with a query (like `mongo` or `postgres`).

For example, I want to execute some logic for players in the lobby. I want to update the user status to `lobby` only if it was in `home`.
Applying this logic in the app won't work since I may encounter a race condition between 2 processes.
I would do something like this in mongo:

```
update({id:1, status:home}, {status: lobby})
```

This way I will receive the result (success or fail) if the update was successful, and it is atomic.

How can I do it in `redis`?

Answer (score 1):

There's no update-by-query in Redis, like in other document stores/RDBMSs

You can either go with [MULTI-EXEC transactions](https://redis.io/topics/transactions) or [EVAL / EVAL SHA](https://redis.io/commands/eval) to perform atomic updates and compose a batch of commands together

Redis uses a single thread for command processing (as of this moment), so evaluating a script would be performed atomically, and would probably be more straight forward approach than multi-exec.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a LUA procedure:

```
eval "local ks=redis.call('keys','user:*') for k=1,#ks do print(k) if (redis.call('hget',ks[k],'status') == KEYS[1]) then redis.call('hset',ks[k],'status',KEYS[2]) end end" 2 home lobby
```

> 127.0.0.1:6370> hset user:1 id 1   (integer) 1
>   127.0.0.1:6370> hset user:1 status outside   (integer) 1
>   127.0.0.1:6370> hset user:2 id 2   (integer) 1
>   127.0.0.1:6370> hset user:2 status home   (integer) 1
>   127.0.0.1:6370> eval "local ks=redis.call('keys','user:*') for k=1,#ks do print(k) if (redis.call('hget',ks[k],'status') == KEYS[1]) then
>   redis.call('hset',ks[k],'status',KEYS[2]) end end" 2 home lobby
>   (nil)
>   127.0.0.1:6370> hgetall user:2   1) "id"   2) "2"   3) "status"   4) "lobby"
>   127.0.0.1:6370> hgetall user:1   1) "id"   2) "1"   3) "status"   4) "outside"